# Remove Starbucks badge from iPhone Lock Screen

Tags: iphone, ios, wallet

I’ve tried all of the solutions I could find but none of them have worked. I also called Starbucks customer service several times but nobody could help me. Can anyone offer any new suggestions?

[image: Starbucks badge on iPhone Lock Screen]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Your post is missing **a lot** of info so as it's currently written, I doubt you'll get any answers.  See [ask] for info on how to ask questions here including the device, iOS version, steps you've already taken, error messages, etc.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with a screenshot of what you’re seeing?

Comment: Here is the screenshot that you asked for:

Answer (score 2):

Open your Starbucks Card by opening the **Wallet** app. Tap the ⓘ in the bottom-right corner:
[image]

Now *disable* **Suggest on Lock Screen**:
[image]

Alternatively, you can also remove your Favorite Stores from within the **Starbucks** app. Those are the ones that cause the Starbucks Card to show up on the Lock Screen when nearby.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Great to hear. Feel free to upvote/accept my answer when you get a chance (click the check mark next to it)

Comment: I turned that off and also removed the store from my "favorites" - and at least immediately it didn't go away.   I'll wait a little while and see...